# Spring MVC model keeps attribute from previous request for same mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When I was testing a controller, I found out that following code works without problems.
But I do not understand why model contains "passProperty" attribute after returning in post mapping.
PassProperty class is only annotated with validation constraints.
In controller it is annotated only with @Valid annotation in a method as you can see in code below.

I have following mappings in a controller:

Get:

```
@GetMapping("/accounts/change-password")
public ModelAndView changePass(Principal principal) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("change-password");
    mv.addObject("passProperties", new PassProperties());

    return mv;
}
```

Post:

```
@PostMapping("/accounts/change-password")
public ModelAndView changePass(@Valid PassProperties passProperties, BindingResult bindingResult, Principal principal) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("change-password");

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors() == false) {
        User user = userService.findUser(principal.getName());
        String oldPass = passProperties.getOldPass();

        if (encoder.matches(oldPass, user.getPassword())) {
            user.setPassword(encoder.encode(passProperties.getNewPass1()));
            userService.saveUser(user);
            mv.addObject("msg", "Hasło zostało zmienione");
        } else {
            mv.addObject("msg", "Stare hasło nie pasuje.");
        }

    }

    return mv;
}
```

## Edit 1

I am adding following test and output.
As you can see returned ModelAndView contains passProperties that were not added in the @PostMapping method. The passProperties object is only annotated with @Valid and in PassProperties class fields are annotated with constraints @NotNull, @Length and @NotBlank. It is not annotated anywhere with anything like @ModelAttribute.
Test:

```
@Test
void changePassPost_whenPassPropertiesHasNoErrors_returnsModelWithPassProperties_And_ChangesPassword() throws Exception {
    User principal = new User ("user", "user", true, "LVL99");

    PassProperties passProperties = new PassProperties();
    passProperties.setOldPass("user");
    passProperties.setNewPass1("zaq1");
    passProperties.setNewPass2("zaq1");

    when(userService.findUser("user")).thenReturn(principal);
    when(encoder.encode(passProperties.getNewPass1())).thenReturn(passProperties.getNewPass1());
    when(encoder.matches(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(true);

    ModelAndView mv = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/accounts/change-password")
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(new UserDetailsImpl(principal)))
                .param("oldPass", passProperties.getOldPass())
                .param("newPass1", passProperties.getNewPass1())
                .param("newPass2", passProperties.getNewPass2())
            )
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("passProperties"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().hasNoErrors())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("change-password"))
            .andReturn().getModelAndView();

    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println(mv.getModel().get("passProperties"));
    System.out.println(mv.getModel().get("msg"));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");

    ArgumentCaptor<User> userCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(User.class);
    verify(encoder, times(1)).encode(passProperties.getNewPass1());
    verify(userService, times(1)).saveUser(userCaptor.capture());
    assertEquals(passProperties.getNewPass1(), userCaptor.getValue().getPassword());
    assertEquals(passProperties.getNewPass1(), principal.getPassword());

}
```

Output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /accounts/change-password
       Parameters = {oldPass=[user], newPass1=[zaq1], newPass2=[zaq1], _csrf=[8fc305ee-f0eb-42a6-8588-cce3ffdba469]}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@a37a47df: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@a37a47df: Principal: com.example.JabaVeans.service.UserDetailsImpl@58e46572; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: LVL99}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.JabaVeans.controller.AccountsController
           Method = com.example.JabaVeans.controller.AccountsController#changePass(PassProperties, BindingResult, Principal)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = change-password
             View = null
        Attribute = passProperties
            value = PassProperties(oldPass=user, newPass1=zaq1, newPass2=zaq1)
           errors = []
        Attribute = msg
            value = Hasło zostało zmienione

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Language:"en", Content-Type:"text/html;charset=UTF-8", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = text/html;charset=UTF-8
             Body = <!DOCTYPE html>

    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
-------------------------------
PassProperties(oldPass=user, newPass1=zaq1, newPass2=zaq1)
Hasło zostało zmienione
-------------------------------

2020-08-22 18:01:49.655  INFO 12964 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-08-22 18:01:49.665  INFO 12964 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Edit 2

I know that I can override "passProperties" with new PassProperties in @PostMapping to erase previous values but I am really confused why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your PassProperties class, maybe it has some validation annotations, like @NotNull, @Min, @Max, @Email, @Size, etc.
Using the @Valid annotation in your Controller, Spring will check if PassProperties object is valid based on validation annotations that you has defined in your class. If some field of your PassProperties object is not valid, the method will not start and spring returns a error based in it.

I believe that PassProperties has some attributes related to password, like oldPass, newPass. Based in your code, the method changePass from @GetMapping is just returning a new object instance of class PassProperties. The @PostMapping of changePass is receiving a PassProperties object, probabilly sent by some user, in this case, like I've explained above, only will work if all validations is true (because of @Valid annotation).

Comment: This is not an issue. 
After @PostMapping of changePass successfuly finished processing and returns ModelAndView mv, the model still contains the passProperties attribute with same values that were passed to the method before.

Comment: Moreover after calling mv.clear() on the end of method just before return, the passProperties is still present in the model and can be accessed/displayed for example via th:text

Comment: ok, now I've understood your question, I'll edit my answer